# How can I map two different foreign key with same primary key in different table?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a table named as **EnrollTrainee**. I have these columns in my EnrollTrainee Model Class:

```
[Key]
public int id { get; set; }

public int TraineeID { get; set; }      

public int TrainerID { ![enter image description here][1]get; set; }

public virtual CreateUsers user_userid { get; set; }

public virtual CreateUsers user_id { get; set; }

public DateTime dt { get; set; }
```

These two Columns **TraineeID** and **TrainerID** are to be mapped with **User_id** Column in table **CreateUser**.

Here is **CreateUser** Model Class

```
    public class CreateUsers
    {
    [Key]
      public int User_Userid { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Enter User Name")]
    public string User_name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote("IsDomainIDExist", "Account", ErrorMessage = "Domain ID Already Exist")]
    [Display(Name = "Enter Domain ID")]
    public string User_username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Enter Password")]
    public string User_password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Enter Department")]
    public string User_department { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote("IsEmployeeIDExist", "Account", ErrorMessage = "Domain ID Already Exist")]
    [Display(Name = "Enter Employee ID")]
    public string User_employeeid { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Select Role Type")]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Enable?")]
    public bool User_Enable { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Date Time")]
    public DateTime dt { get; set; }

    public virtual RoleModel Role { get; set; }

 }
```

How can I map two Foreign Key with same Primary Key in EF CF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public class EnrollTrainee
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int TraineeID { get; set; }

    public virtual CreateUser Trainee { get; set; }

    public int TrainerID { get; set; }

    public virtual CreateUser Trainer { get; set; }

    public DateTime dt { get; set; }
}

internal class EnrollTraineeConfiguration:EntityTypeConfiguration<EnrollTrainee>
{
    public EnrollTraineeConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("EnrollTrainee");
        Property(c => c.dt).HasColumnName("dt");
        Property(c => c.TraineeID).HasColumnName("TraineeID");
        Property(c => c.TrainerID).HasColumnName("TrainerID");
        HasKey(c => c.id);
        HasRequired(c => c.Trainee).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c=>c.TraineeId);
        HasRequired(c => c.Trainer).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.TrainerId);
    }
}
public class Context: DbContext
{
     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
          modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EnrollTraineeConfiguration());
          ......
     }
     ....
}
```

Comment: HasRequired(c => c.Trainee).WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.Id);.. c.ID is the Primary key of the other table. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: It is giving me error in **c.ID** :- Cannot Implicitly convert type **int** to **Model.EnrollTrainee**

Comment: Please Check Createusers Model Class.

Comment: I update my answer. use HasRequired(c => c.Trainee).WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.User_Userid);
        HasRequired(c => c.Trainer).WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.User_Userid);

Comment: I have already changed Id to User_Userid ,I am getting this Error **Cannot Implicitly convert type int to Model.EnrollTrainee**

Comment: Hmmm... Try to use HasRequired(c => c.Trainee).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(c=>c.User_Userid)

Comment: Withoptional does not have any HasForeignkey Property.

Comment: Hmm. It's true. Try HasRequired(c => c.Trainee).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c=>c.User_Userid) then.

Comment: C lambda getting Column from EnrollTrainee table not from Create Users table

Comment: It could be. Not so simple write all this without VisualStudio.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MVC3 or 4 then you can use Entity Framework mapping to do the same, which in turn will generate the required classes.
Model browser you can use to do the same.

What you have to do:

Create your tables
Create PK and FK Constraints in the Table
Right Click on the Model folder in the solution explorer in your project
select Add New Item, from "Data" category, select ADO.Net EF 4.x/5.x
Click Ok
It will open an wizard , give the required parameters, on the way select your tables where it will ask for.
When finished it will simply create an .Edmx file, in the context file of the .Edmx, i

Comment: you are talking about Design First Approach and i am working on Code first Approach